# Jquery map hilight, how do I change this to work onclick?

Tags: jquery, dictionary

I am trying to get map highlight to work onclick, but I am not sure where to start. Here is the code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.map').maphilight();


        });

    </script>

<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="map">

<img class="map" src="Iceclimbing_test.jpg" width="944" height="1107" usemap="#Map" border="0" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area id="helmet" shape="poly" coords="361,415,367,409,373,405,378,400,383,396,387,390,391,383,394,376,398,368,402,362,399,358,394,358,389,356,380,352,371,350,363,349,352,350,345,354,336,360,330,366,324,372,320,379,317,384,313,389,310,396,308,403,308,410,311,415,314,419,312,422,313,429,317,437,323,443,327,449,350,439,353,431,356,424" href="#" alt="Helmet" />
</map>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the plugin code:

```
(function (F) {
    var B, C, I, L, K, H, E, G, A, J;
    B = document.namespaces;
    has_canvas = !! document.createElement("canvas").getContext;
    if (!(has_canvas || B)) {
        F.fn.maphilight = function () {
            return this
        };
        return
    }
    if (has_canvas) {
        E = function (M) {
            return Math.max(0, Math.min(parseInt(M, 16), 255))
        };
        G = function (M, N) {
            return "rgba(" + E(M.substr(0, 2)) + "," + E(M.substr(2, 2)) + "," + E(M.substr(4, 2)) + "," + N + ")"
        };
        C = function (M) {
            var N = F('<canvas style="width:' + M.width + "px;height:" + M.height + 'px;"></canvas>').get(0);
            N.getContext("2d").clearRect(0, 0, N.width, N.height);
            return N
        };
        I = function (P, M, S, O, N) {
            var R, Q = P.getContext("2d");
            Q.beginPath();
            if (M == "rect") {
                Q.rect(S[0], S[1], S[2] - S[0], S[3] - S[1])
            } else {
                if (M == "poly") {
                    Q.moveTo(S[0], S[1]);
                    for (R = 2; R < S.length; R += 2) {
                        Q.lineTo(S[R], S[R + 1])
                    }
                } else {
                    if (M == "circ") {
                        Q.arc(S[0], S[1], S[2], 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
                    }
                }
            }
            Q.closePath();
            if (O.fill) {
                Q.fillStyle = G(O.fillColor, O.fillOpacity);
                Q.fill()
            }
            if (O.stroke) {
                Q.strokeStyle = G(O.strokeColor, O.strokeOpacity);
                Q.lineWidth = O.strokeWidth;
                Q.stroke()
            }
            if (O.fade) {
                F(P).css("opacity", 0).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 100)
            }
        };
        L = function (M) {
            M.getContext("2d").clearRect(0, 0, M.width, M.height)
        }
    } else {
        C = function (M) {
            return F('<var style="zoom:1;overflow:hidden;display:block;width:' + M.width + "px;height:" + M.height + 'px;"></var>').get(0)
        };
        I = function (N, Q, R, U, M) {
            var S, T, O, P;
            S = '<v:fill color="#' + U.fillColor + '" opacity="' + (U.fill ? U.fillOpacity : 0) + '" />';
            T = (U.stroke ? 'strokeweight="' + U.strokeWidth + '" stroked="t" strokecolor="#' + U.strokeColor + '"' : 'stroked="f"');
            O = '<v:stroke opacity="' + U.strokeOpacity + '"/>';
            if (Q == "rect") {
                P = F('<v:rect name="' + M + '" filled="t" ' + T + ' style="zoom:1;margin:0;padding:0;display:block;position:absolute;left:' + R[0] + "px;top:" + R[1] + "px;width:" + (R[2] - R[0]) + "px;height:" + (R[3] - R[1]) + 'px;"></v:rect>')
            } else {
                if (Q == "poly") {
                    P = F('<v:shape name="' + M + '" filled="t" ' + T + ' coordorigin="0,0" coordsize="' + N.width + "," + N.height + '" path="m ' + R[0] + "," + R[1] + " l " + R.join(",") + ' x e" style="zoom:1;margin:0;padding:0;display:block;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:' + N.width + "px;height:" + N.height + 'px;"></v:shape>')
                } else {
                    if (Q == "circ") {
                        P = F('<v:oval name="' + M + '" filled="t" ' + T + ' style="zoom:1;margin:0;padding:0;display:block;position:absolute;left:' + (R[0] - R[2]) + "px;top:" + (R[1] - R[2]) + "px;width:" + (R[2] * 2) + "px;height:" + (R[2] * 2) + 'px;"></v:oval>')
                    }
                }
            }
            P.get(0).innerHTML = S + O;
            F(N).append(P)
        };
        L = function (M) {
            F(M).find("[name=highlighted]").remove()
        }
    }
    K = function (N) {
        var M, O = N.getAttribute("coords").split(",");
        for (M = 0; M < O.length; M++) {
            O[M] = parseFloat(O[M])
        }
        return [N.getAttribute("shape").toLowerCase().substr(0, 4), O]
    };
    J = function (O, N) {
        var M = F(O);
        return F.extend({}, N, F.metadata ? M.metadata() : false, M.data("maphilight"))
    };
    A = function (M) {
        if (!M.complete) {
            return false
        }
        if (typeof M.naturalWidth != "undefined" && M.naturalWidth == 0) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    };
    H = {
        position: "absolute",
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        padding: 0,
        border: 0
    };
    var D = false;
    F.fn.maphilight = function (O) {
        O = F.extend({}, F.fn.maphilight.defaults, O);
        if (!has_canvas && F.browser.msie && !D) {
            document.namespaces.add("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
            var N = document.createStyleSheet();
            var M = ["shape", "rect", "oval", "circ", "fill", "stroke", "imagedata", "group", "textbox"];
            F.each(M, function () {
                N.addRule("v\\:" + this, "behavior: url(#default#VML); antialias:true")
            });
            D = true
        }
        return this.each(function () {
            var U, R, Y, Q, T, V, X, S, W;
            U = F(this);
            if (!A(this)) {
                return window.setTimeout(function () {
                    U.maphilight(O)
                }, 200)
            }
            Y = F.extend({}, O, F.metadata ? U.metadata() : false, U.data("maphilight"));
            W = U.get(0).getAttribute("usemap");
            Q = F('map[name="' + W.substr(1) + '"]');
            if (!(U.is("img") && W && Q.size() > 0)) {
                return
            }
            if (U.hasClass("maphilighted")) {
                var P = U.parent();
                U.insertBefore(P);
                P.remove();
                F(Q).unbind(".maphilight").find("area[coords]").unbind(".maphilight")
            }
            R = F("<div></div>").css({
                display: "block",
                background: 'url("' + this.src + '")',
                position: "relative",
                padding: 0,
                width: this.width,
                height: this.height
            });
            if (Y.wrapClass) {
                if (Y.wrapClass === true) {
                    R.addClass(F(this).attr("class"))
                } else {
                    R.addClass(Y.wrapClass)
                }
            }
            U.before(R).css("opacity", 0).css(H).remove();
            if (F.browser.msie) {
                U.css("filter", "Alpha(opacity=0)")
            }
            R.append(U);
            T = C(this);
            F(T).css(H);
            T.height = this.height;
            T.width = this.width;
            X = function (b) {
                var Z, a;
                a = J(this, Y);
                if (!a.neverOn && !a.alwaysOn) {
                    Z = K(this);
                    I(T, Z[0], Z[1], a, "highlighted");
                    if (a.groupBy && F(this).attr(a.groupBy)) {
                        var c = this;
                        Q.find("area[" + a.groupBy + '="' + F(this).attr(a.groupBy) + '"]').each(function () {
                            if (this != c) {
                                var e = J(this, Y);
                                if (!e.neverOn && !e.alwaysOn) {
                                    var d = K(this);
                                    I(T, d[0], d[1], e, "highlighted")
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    if (!has_canvas) {
                        F(T).append("<v:rect></v:rect>")
                    }
                }
            };
            F(Q).bind("alwaysOn.maphilight", function () {
                if (V) {
                    L(V)
                }
                if (!has_canvas) {
                    F(T).empty()
                }
                F(Q).find("area[coords]").each(function () {
                    var Z, a;
                    a = J(this, Y);
                    if (a.alwaysOn) {
                        if (!V && has_canvas) {
                            V = C(U.get());
                            F(V).css(H);
                            V.width = U.width();
                            V.height = U.height();
                            U.before(V)
                        }
                        a.fade = a.alwaysOnFade;
                        Z = K(this);
                        if (has_canvas) {
                            I(V, Z[0], Z[1], a, "")
                        } else {
                            I(T, Z[0], Z[1], a, "")
                        }
                    }
                })
            });
            F(Q).trigger("alwaysOn.maphilight").find("area[coords]").bind("mouseenter.maphilight", X).bind("mouseout.maphilight", function (Z) {
                L(T)
            });
            U.before(T);
            U.addClass("maphilighted")
        })
    };
    F.fn.maphilight.defaults = {
        fill: true,
        fillColor: "FFFFFF",
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        stroke: true,
        strokeColor: "EEEEEE",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWidth: 1,
        fade: true,
        alwaysOn: false,
        neverOn: false,
        groupBy: false,
        wrapClass: true
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Obviously I have included the jquery library and the plugin on the site I am working on

Comment: Thanks for the obfuscated, minified plugin code :s

Comment: Start from any javascript book for newbies.

Comment: Thank you Vision I was just looking for the unminified my self. I didn't really need all the sarcastic comments from the others though

Comment: It's actually not sarcastic - it's a real advice. You've come to a developers community. It's supposed you know and want to develop yourself. It's not a charity or volunteers who do the work for you place.

Comment: Fair enough. I was actually looking for advice on where to start. Admittedly I am just starting to learn the simple stuff and I was curious on how I would go about editing this plugin to do what I am trying to achieve. I thought it was a community that helped people regardless of there competence

Comment: @Ashley Briscoe: "starting to learn the simple stuff" -- so start with real **simple** stuff. It's too early for you to do such things yet. "regardless of there competence" --- if someone comes and asks how to build a rocket and doesn't even know how the rockets look like - it's just impossible to help. It's only possible to do the work for you, and the sad thing - is that you'll not learn anything from that (because of lack of competence).

Comment: @zerkms Wow you angry today :)

Comment: @VisioN: I always am ;-) PS: but am I actually that wrong right now?

Comment: @zerkms You are correct.

Comment: @zerkms Nope, I agree with you. It is always better to learn new things from "Hello, World".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having scanned through the online docs, there is no option to highlight an area on mouse click. That said, it should be pretty straightforward to modify the script to get what you want. Take a look [here on line 318](https://github.com/kemayo/maphilight/blob/master/jquery.maphilight.js#L318):

```
$(map).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight').find('area[coords]')
      .bind('mouseover.maphilight', mouseover)
      .bind('mouseout.maphilight', function(e) { clear_canvas(canvas); });
```

You could try changing it to this:

```
$(map).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight').find('area[coords]')
      .bind('click.maphilight', mouseover)
      .bind('mouseout.maphilight', function(e) { clear_canvas(canvas); });
```

I reckon that will do the trick, but it will still clear the canvas when you move the mouse out of the clicked area.

That should be a start.

*Disclaimer: I don't know if this will work at all.*

Comment: I had been scanning the online docs too and couldn't find any information on this either. thankyou for your input. I will try what you have suggested.